# How to make server play sound when receiving request

Tags: audio, go

I want to make a server play a soundbyte every time it receives a request.  Is there  a way to do this if I'm using a Go based server?  The idea would be the server is hosting a browser window, it receives a request and the browser goes 'ping!'.

Comment: Just an idea but wouldn't be better to let the front-end Javascript to play the sound data from the Go server using libraries like [timbre.js](http://mohayonao.github.io/timbre.js/) or [osc.js](https://github.com/colinbdclark/osc.js?files=1) since it doesn't seem like the server's task to interface with the audio hardware directly?

Comment: Ya that helps.  It's just for a demo of a load balancer I'm working on

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which operating system you want the code to work. Afaik there is no generic cross-platform solution for playing sound from go:

- On Linux you might need to rely on Pulse Audio with a package such as [github.com/mesilliac/pulse-simple](https://github.com/mesilliac/pulse-simple)
- On Windows and Mac you could use PortAudio with a package such as [github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio](https://github.com/gordonklaus/portaudio)

If you want a practical example there is a go-based multi-source music player project called "moggio" at [github.com/mjibson/moggio](https://github.com/mjibson/moggio) that plays audio from multiple sources on Linux, Mac and Windows.

You can have a look at the [github.com/mjibson/moggio/output](https://github.com/mjibson/moggio/tree/master/output) package. There you will find the code that moggio used to play music on Linux, Windows and Mac.